# Read PEM certificate on Flask

Tags: python, flask, ssl, client-certificates

Basically, I want to be able to ask the user for it's personal P12 certificate in order to resend it to a government page and retrieve some information with it. I know this could be simply done asking the user to select the path of his local certificate and send it, but average users will have no clue where his local certificates are.

Therefore, my question is: is there another way the user can select his local certificate and upload it to my local Flask page without having to manually go to the certificate path?

PS: I have seen several solutions like [this one](https://carolinafernandez.github.io/development/2017/09/13/HTTPS-and-trust-chain-in-Flask), but the thing is that I will not have a server certificate, the Flask webpage will act as a mere intermediate agent to resend the certificate to a government page.

Comment: what do you mean by personal p12 certificate ?. Are you looking for [client authentication](https://comodosslstore.com/blog/what-is-ssl-tls-client-authentication-how-does-it-work.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I mean client authentification

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to check the most common directories for this kind of file, then propose these paths to the user. This one will be helped in the selection of documents.

Either you know the path, the user knows the path, or a search tool does the work for you. These are all the solutions available.